# pointer comparisons "<" with one past the last element of an array object

Tags: c++, c, pointers, comparison

I know the pointer comparisons with `<` is allowed in C standard only when the pointers point at the same memory space (like array).

if we take an array:

```
int array[10];
int *ptr = &array[0];
```

is comparing  `ptr` to `array+10` allowed? Is the `array+10` pointer considered outside the array memory and so the comparison is not allowed?

example

```
for(ptr=&array[0]; ptr<(array+10); ptr++) {...}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, a pointer is permitted to point to the location just past the end of the array.  However you aren't permitted to deference such a pointer.

> C99 6.5.6/8 Additive operators (emphasis added)
>
> if the expression P points to the last element of an array object, the
>   expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object,
>   and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array
>   object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array
>   object. If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements
>   of the same array object, **or one past the last element of the array
>   object**, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined. If the result points one past the last element
>   of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary *
>   operator that is evaluated.

And, specifically for comparision operations on pointers:

> C99 6.5.8/5 Relational operators
>
> If the expression P points to an element of an array object and the
>   expression Q points to the last element of the same array object, the
>   pointer expression Q+1 compares greater than P. In all other cases,
>   the behavior is undefined.

Comment: is it the same case for `one post the first element`?

Comment: @MOHAMED you mean one *before* the first element? No, that is strictly forbidden :)

Comment: @jalf yes I mean one before the first element. thank you for the answer. are there some standards prouves? some SO links?

Comment: @MOHAMED Read this very answer. The quote above from 6.5.6/8 says everything you need to know. The evaluation is undefined if operands and result do not point into the array or one past the last element. In other words, one *before* the start of the element is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is allowed, and C++ relies heavily on it (C doesn't use it quite as much, but in C++, a very common way to denote ranges is by have a pointer (or more generally, an iterator) pointing to the first element, and another pointing one *past* the end of the range.

It is legal for such a pointer to exist, and to compare it against the rest of the array.

But it is not legal to ever dereference the pointer.

Comment: do you know why comparing pointers is allowed only when they point to same array... seems weird to me... what if i have a bunch of objects and I want to put them in std::map where key is their address ?(I want them ordered but i dont care how, so i use their addr)

Comment: `std::map` gets around this by using `std::less` as the default comparator. It does basically the same as `<`, *except that it is guaranteed to work for pointers pointing into different arrays/objects*. :)

Comment: As for *why* this restriction exists, I believe it is to support non-linear memory systems, such as (but not limited to) older systems with segmented memory, and where a "less than" comparison between arbitrary pointers may be meaningless, or more expensive to compute. So you have `std::less` for the case where "I want an ordering, and I don't care which, or how expensive it is", and `<` which does the simple thing, but is only guaranteed to work within a single allocation.

Comment: wow, really great insight, about std less, never ever i thought about it... i thought it was just a nice generic name for < for ints, ptrs... strcmp for strings...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl in practice, it often is just a dumb wrapper around `<`. But the point is that *if* you're compiling for some weird architecture where a more complex computation is needed to guarantee a consistent ordering, then `std::less` provides a place to put it. But yes, normally, it just calls `<` directly. :)