# Reversing a string with strrev - C

Tags: c, string, itoa

I'm trying to reverse a string using the function strrev(). I know that strrev returns a pointer to the reversed string so I simply initialize an already allocated string with same size as the original one with the strrev function return. Obviously this isn't the correct way to do it and I get an "incompatible types" error in that line.

Here's the code:

```
int ispalindrome(int n)
{
   char s[10], sr[10];

   itoa(n, s, 10);

   printf("%s", s);

   sr = strrev(s);

   printf("\nReverse: %s", sr);

   if(strcmp(s, sr) == 0)
       return 1;

   else
       return 0;

}
```

Comment: `itoa` is a nonstandard function, suggested function to use is `sprintf` as per http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sr[10];
sr = strrev(s);
```

This doesn't even compile - arrays are not assignable. **Post real code.**

(You need to declare `sr` as `char *sr` for this to actually compile at all.)

---

Apart from that, your issue is that `strrev()` reverses the string in place, so the two strings will always compare equal (since you're effectively comparing the reversed string with itself). What you have to do is:

- superfluously inefficient way: create a copy of the string, `strrev()` that, then `strcmp()` the original and the copy.
- Somewhat more optimized approach for non-empty strings:

---

```
int ispal(const char *s)
{
    const char *p = s + strlen(s) - 1;
    while (s < p)
        if (*p-- != *s++)
            return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I think the question was about the code not compiling. Well, part of it anyway, I didn't really see a `?` anywhere.

Comment: I liked the code snippet, even though it was not an answer to the original question.

Comment: This code is not correct if you pass in the empty string... it exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @H2CO3 when s is "", p will point to s-1. See the excellent first answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234626/pointer-comparisons-with-one-before-the-first-element-of-an-array-object why this is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Anonymous Ah, off-by-one. Fixed.

Comment: Nope, in the case that `strlen(s) == 0` then `p = s-1`, and `while (s < p)` gives undefined behavior because p isn't valid.

Comment: @Anonymous That's what I'm saying. I've read the answer you linked.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31283/discussion-between-anonymous-and-h2co3)

Comment: @H2CO3 Anonymous is right.you could either introduce a null string check or do this `const char *p = s + strlen(s)` and then `if(*--p != *s++)`.

Comment: @Koushik I've included "for non-empty strings" in the answer, and that's enough. I'm not interested in discussing this point further.

Answer (score 2):

OK, did some research and looks like `strrev` is not available in Linux (if that is your platform); check out [Is the strrev() function not available in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534274/is-strrev-function-not-available-in-linux)

You can use the alternative implementation suggested therein or use the answer by @H2CO3.