# Will "&a+1 > &a" cause an undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, c, c99, c++03

Does `c99/c++03` guarantee that `&a+1 > &a` is always true?

for example, there's a (c-like) `std::copy`, and

```
int a = 0 ;
int b[9] ;
std__copy(&a , &a+1 , b) ;
```

Does this always work?

Comment: may be the same of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233868/pointer-comparisons-with-one-past-the-last-element-of-an-array-object

Comment: Yes, although the answer @MOHAMED is referrint to talks about an array, it's the same principle for a simple object.

Comment: @MOHAMED, no that isn't the same.  There is no question for the case of an array, but for a non array variable there has to be special wording.

Comment: From memory the answer if UB for C90 and C++98, valid for C11 and C++11 but I don't remember if the clarification was made in time for C99 and C++03 ;-(

Comment: this link could be useful too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234626/pointer-comparisons-with-one-before-the-first-element-of-an-array-object

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, C99 has special wording to say that when working with addresses, any given object `a` will act like an array of 1 item, so that `&a+1` is valid (§6.5.6/7):

> For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an
>   array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the
>   type of the object as its element type.

Though the section number is different (§6.3.6), C90 gives the same requirement.

C++ has the same requirement in §5.7/4 (same section number in both C++03 and C++11).

In C++, you can compare addresses of arbitrary objects (of the same type) using `std::less`, even when the built in `<` operator would not yield meaningful results (e.g., two objects that are not parts of the same array) (§20.8.5/7):

> For templates `greater`, `less`, `greater_equal`, and `less_equal`, the specializations for any pointer type yield a total order, even if the built-in operators <, >, <=, >= do not.

Also note that although you can form these addresses, and can compare them to the address of the object, you *cannot* dereference these pointers (well, the compiler probably won't stop you if you try, but the result will be undefined behavior).

Comment: Interesting, I never knew `std::less` worked for comparing arbitrary addresses. How exactly does the standard guarantee that?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is guaranteed in C++ (don't know about C). The specifics is that a variable of type T is equivalent to an array of a single element of the same type, and you can always obtain a pointer beyond the end of an array.

Comment: if it has the same prinicipe of array object you have to mention in the answer that pointer deferencing of `&a+1` is forbidden

Comment: @MOHAMED: well, the OP doesn't dereference it, so it's not very relevant to the answer either :)

Comment: I know Just to make him more careful when using such behavior :-)

Comment: @MOHAMED: The example he has is similar to `std::copy`, and inside that template the `end` iterator is never derreferenced. You are right, and maybe I should be more explicit, but if the intention is passing a single object to an implementation of a function that works on *ranges* (in the sense of pair of iterators) it is perfectly valid.