# Is it ok to have a pointer to an invalid location if you don't use it?

Tags: c, ansi-c

Here's a simple program to explain what I mean. Given a length n, it initializes a sequence of n integers read by standard input.

```
int n, *seq, *current;
scanf("%d", &n);
seq = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
for (current = seq; current - seq < n; current++)
  scanf("%d", current);
```

My doubt is about the last increment of `current` which makes it point to something outside the allocated memory. Obviously it is an error to read from that location. But what if I don't read that location?

The program runs correctly, but my question is: it is a standard and good practice or is it something that may cause troubles and should be avoided?

**UPDATE:** And what about appending this to the end of the previous program?

```
for (current--; current - seq >= 0; current--)
  printf("%d\n", *current);
```

According to @MOHAMED answer it is wrong, not because it is an access to an invalid location, but because the `current - seq >= 0` may give wrong results when `current` points to one location before the first element, thus having an undefined value!

Comment: It's absolutely fine. You can POINT to anything you like. Just don't dereference it unless it's valid! :) It's a bit cleaner if you use an int as your counter, then reference data in seq as seq[counter]. But there's nothing fundamentally wrong with what you're doing

Comment: A pointer is just a variable whose type is suitable for holding memory addresses. You should not confuse values and statements. A statement is not allowed to access invalid memory. A value doesn't access anything; it's just a value and doesn't do anything.

Comment: One-past-the-end isn't an invalid location, it's just not a location you're allowed to dereference. Actual invalid values (e.g. dangling or uninitialized pointers) are OK, too, but you must not perform any operations on the pointer itself.

Comment: Sounds unavoidable to me.  As soon as the stack frame is generated with space for the auto pointers, the pointers 'exist' and are, as yet, uninitialised and probably point to an invalid location.

Comment: A method to achieve the updated functionality: `for (; --current > seq; ) printf("%d\n", *current);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233868/pointer-comparisons-with-one-past-the-last-element-of-an-array-object):

Yes, a pointer is permitted to point to the location just past the end of the array.  However you aren't permitted to deference such a pointer.

> C99 6.5.6/8 Additive operators (emphasis added)
>
> if the expression P points to the last element of an array object, the
>   expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object,
>   and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array
>   object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array
>   object. If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements
>   of the same array object, **or one past the last element of the array
>   object**, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined. If the result points one past the last element
>   of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary *
>   operator that is evaluated.

**Concerning your UPDATE**

And according to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234626/pointer-comparisons-with-one-before-the-first-element-of-an-array-object):

The comparison `current - seq >= 0` is **undefined behavior** in your case: `current - seq` becomes undefined when `current` is decremented after the iteration when it is equal to `seq`.

This is covered by section 6.5.6 of the standard, part 8:

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression. In other words, if the expression `P` points to the i-th element of an array object, the expressions `(P)+N` (equivalently, `N+(P)`) and `(P)-N` (where `N` has the value `n`) point to, respectively, the `i+n`-th and `i−n`-th elements of the array object, provided they exist. Moreover, if the expression `P` points to the last element of an array object, the expression `(P)+1` points one past the last element of the array object, and if the expression `Q` points one past the last element of an array object, the expression `(Q)-1` points to the last element of the array object. If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined**. If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary `*` operator that is evaluated.

The standard goes length to cover the element at the position one past the last element of the array object, while the element at the position one prior the first element falls under the "otherwise" clause of the above rule.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my question according to your answer.

Comment: @collimarco I updated my answer according to your update

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use the pointer again (unless you reassign it) then it's okay.

Just *having* a pointer doesn't cause undefined behavior, it's when and how you use it that can cause problems. So if you don't use it nothing will happen.

Comment: It's better than that, though: You can do pointer arithmetic with the one-past-the-end pointer. It's quite a nice pointer.

Comment: Adding to create a one-past-the-end pointer is supported by the C standard. Creating other pointers outside an array is not.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine, but the following is probably clearer and less error prone:

```
int n, *seq, counter;
scanf("%d", &n);
seq = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
for (counter = 0; counter < n; counter++)
  scanf("%d", &seq[counter]);
```